# HTTP 500 error when updating a page

Tags: 500-internal-error, troubleshooting

We got a Wordpress site, designed by an external contractor a couple years ago. https://playbacktheatre.com.au

We recently (Dec 2019) changed hosting providers in search of a better service. After the migration the site was working smoothly and it was much faster, as we hoped it would be.

Recently though we got a problem with the home page throwing an HTTP 500 error. I believe this was triggered by the update of one of the pages  (https://playbacktheatre.com.au/performances/) using the Wordpress admin panel. Only the home page throws this error, all other pages seem to be working ok.

I asked for a restoration of a previous state from our provider and they did it. (I later found that they restored only a single folder [httpdocs] that contains just the static files and the code. They did not restore the database, nor the plugins, nor Wordpress itself.) The problem was gone! I then I did the update on the page I wanted again (performances/). The problem with the home page reappeared.

I started digging in, using the tools our hosting provider has (Plesk). I found the 500 error in the logs. Here's the error:

> .953468 [NOTICE] [960332]
>   [103.27.34.22:38726-1#APVH_playbacktheatre.com.au:lsapi] [STDERR] PHP
>   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in
>   /var/www/vhosts/playbacktheatre.com.au/httpdocs/site/wp-content/themes/playback/front-page.php
>   on line 186

I browsed the front-page.php file trying to find something obviously wrong with line 186 (I am not familiar with php, but I am comfortable with programming and other languages). I could not see anything wrong. Then I restored again the website to a prior working state (I found how to do it on my own, I restored only the httpdocs folder) and checked that the home page was working. I browsed again the front-page.php in the hope of finding something different. The file was **exactly** the same as before (compared with diff). I am puzzled with this. How come the error appears in one case and not the other? Is it a matter of different portions of the php script running? I would expect a syntax error like this to throw an error regardless.

I am happy to post the full php file here (191 lines) but just to give you a taste, the offending endif statement is the second to last.

```
    <?php if( have_rows('page_previews') ): while ( have_rows('page_previews') ) : the_row(); ?>

        <?
        $post_object = get_sub_field('page');

        $useCustom = get_sub_field('custom_content');
        $cTitle = get_sub_field('custom_title');
        $cSubtitle = get_sub_field('custom_subtitle');
        $cText = get_sub_field('custom_excerpt');
        $linkType = get_sub_field('link');
        $align = get_sub_field('text_align');

        if($post_object) :

           $post = $post_object;
           setup_postdata( $post );
            ?>

            <section id="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>" class="preview">

 (... more code ...)

        <?php endif;?>    (<- This is line 186)
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Other things that I tried to fix the problem:

- Updates Wordpress from 4.8.x to 5.3.x, and updated plugins using
  Plesk
- Deactivated plugins using the Wordpress admin panel

I can try doing a more full restoration (database and everything) but I am a bit uncertain on how to do this right.
My folder structure is the following:

```
Name    Modified    Size
.cagefs         Dec 20, 2019 03:23 AM
.cl.selector    Feb 5, 2020 03:23 AM    
.pki            Dec 19, 2019 06:43 PM   
.revisium_antivirus_cache   Dec 20, 2019 07:37 PM
.ssh            Dec 21, 2019 01:00 AM   
.wp-cli         Dec 20, 2019 03:24 AM   
error_docs      Dec 19, 2019 06:42 PM   
httpdocs        Dec 20, 2019 06:00 PM   
httpdocs.bak    Dec 20, 2019 05:36 PM
logs            Feb 19, 2020 03:28 AM   
lscache         Dec 20, 2019 02:48 PM   
migration       Dec 20, 2019 12:42 PM   
site.bak        Dec 20, 2019 05:36 PM   
snapshots       Feb 17, 2020 04:19 PM   
wp_h8yyl_2019-12-20_17-33-19.sql.zip Dec 20, 2019 05:33 PM  1.4 MB
```

Any advice is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statment is using an alternative syntax so it needs to be in the following structure which changes the standard opening brace `{` to a colon `:` and the closing brace `}` to `endif;`

```
if ($post_object): 
    // Code if true
    else: 
    // Code if false
endif
```

I'm not sure this will fully fix your problem as there could be different PHP versions on the new server with deprecated functions in the theme, but it should help.

Comment: I'll try it, but this does not explain why the error does not appear when the file is restored (but nothing changes)

Comment: yes, I know. It seems strange.

Comment: I updated the code in my description.

Comment: There are no curly braces in the syntax, and all statements are tagged with <?php> tags (I suppose this code was autogenerated). Not sure if my updated description helps.

Comment: Just to explain more of what is going on, your home page is using front_page.php file as a template. That template is calling the `get_sub_field('page')` function so I suspect whatever is in your performances page is supposed to appear on the front page and that is possibly what is causing the problem.